# In which solaris sparc package does crtbegin and crtend belongs to?

Tags: solaris, sparc, packages

I need to add those two to my paths.

Thus, my plan is to check first if they're already in my machine, and if they are, I'll add them to my path. Otherwise, I'll install them first then add them to my path.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see if the files are installed on your system you can use:

`egrep 'crt(begin|end)' /var/sadm/install/contents`

If they aren't installed, you can grep for them in the Solaris install media:

`egrep 'crt(begin|end)' /cdrom/cdrom0/Solaris_10/Product/*/pkgmap`

Answer (score 1):

They can belong to different packages, especially as you don't tell the full path to them. Assuming you are talking about the gcc run-time objects crtbegin.o and crtend.o, one would be SUNWgcc.

Answer (score 1):

see: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/328/find-which-package-a-file-belongs-to/

google search returns a lot for "solaris file belongs to package"